# Mark messages unread as unread in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

Mozilla Thunderbird (78.13.0) suddenly shows all messages as read, - unread messages are no longer with bold face and no messages show up with I press "Unread" with the "Quick Filter". I suppose that might have been an accidental mishandling of my mail reader, either Mozilla Thunderbird itself ("Mark Folder Read") or a web client that I use.

I am wondering whether it is possible to undo the "read", letting Mozilla Thunderbird indicate the messages that are unread?

Answer (score 1):

Select the messages you want to mark as unread (you can select all messages in the current folder with <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>), right-click on one of them, select the Mark sub-menu, select Unread.

Or, using the menu's keyboard short-cuts: select messages, right-click, press <kbd>k</kbd>, press <kbd>U</kbd>

Note: I only have Thunderbird 68.2.1 installed (I don't use it often, I prefer mutt, and really only use TB for the calendar because it syncs easily with my phone) - things may have changed since that version but it's unlikely - marking messages as Unread has worked the same for as long as I can remember, over 10 years.

Comment: This will indeed make the messages "unread" on my version. However, I would like to have the messages that I have read not being marked as unread. I suppose that information is  irretrievably lost.

Comment: this won't be perfect, but you could mark all messages as read, then pick a date just before whatever happened, happened.  select all messages after that.  mark those as unread. possibly better than nothing because, as you say, the previous read status info is lost.